# Is there a website where you can find complete Projects for learning?

Tags: project

I don't know if I'm right here with the question.
is there a website where you can download examples? for example I would like to learn PHP & SQL communication. I like to learn from working examples and experiment with the parameters. Is there some kind of website where you can find released projects and play around with it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a specific website/service for this, but if you are looking for complete projects to study, maybe there are some open source projects to be found on Github